# How to extend jQuery's AJAX function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, extend

I've played around with creating my own jquery functions, this done via the

```
$.fn.extend({
    myFunc: function () {

    }
});
```

However, after scouring the web and SO for an answer, I would like to ask:

**How can I extend $.ajax()**

The new implementation of `$.ajax` can be used by running

```
$.ajax({

}).done(function (e) {

}).fail(function (e) {

});
```

What I would like to do is to add a `.progress()` so that I don't always have to write

```
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    xhrFields: {
        onprogress: function (e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                console.log(e.loaded /e.total * 100 + '%');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

each time I want to monitor the progress. e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/somewhereorother',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json'
}).progress(function (e) {
    updateProgressBar(e.percentage + '%');
}).done(function (e) {

}).fail(function (e) {

});
```

Comment: jQuery already has [deferred.progress()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.progress/) ?

Comment: Okay, will it work in the context that I described above. What about for future reference for other purposes

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798878/jquery-extend-existing-function

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax` is a function attached to `$` object.

As such, to extend it you would have to store the reference to it somewhere, and call it when needed, something like:

```
var ajax = $.ajax;
$.ajax = function()
{
     if (!arguments[0].success)
     arguments[0].success = function()
     {
          window.alert('done!');
     }

     ajax.apply(ajax, arguments);
}
```

This is a concept (I'm not sure of `this` scope in apply - would have to actually run it) ;) Also, I'd say it's ugly as hell way of doing things.

If you want your `$.ajax` function to differ from official function, I'd still separate it. Either via `$.my_ajax` or by separate namespace (take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.sub/)